# Strcmp() function isn't returning 0

Tags: c, strcmp

i was trying to compare two strings using strcmp() , and in the case they're equal the function returns -1 (meaning they are not equal) , i dont know whats wrong .

```
int main()
{
char password[]={'6','6','6','6','6','6'};
char passmatch[6];
int i =0;
for(i ; i<6 ; i++)
{
    passmatch[i]='6';
}

printf("\n");
if(strcmp(password,passmatch)==0)
{
    printf("Strings are equal");
}
else
{
    printf("String are'nt equal");
}


return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, strings need to be null terminated in order to be used with the standard library. Try putting a '\0' at the end, or make a string literal in the "normal" way, e.g. `char password[] = "666666";`, then the language will automatically put `\0` at the end.

Comment: okay , but what to do in case the user enters the string by himself to be compared with a saved string defined in the main() ?

Comment: It depends on how exactly you get the input but basically you need to guarantee that the resulting string is null-terminated. Most of the standard methods will do this for you.

Comment: my program requires entering a password by the user , and if the password entered by user matches the saved password , application will run , and user must enter password number by number using a keypad , so i save each number in an array of strings and after entering the 6 digits i check if password entered = default password.

Comment: yes, so it matters what exact C code you use to get the user's input, that will determine whether it is null-terminated or not

Comment: I don't think you should expect the user to enter a null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in C `'6'` (with quotes) is not the same as `6` (without quotes). That's why this loop

```
for(i ; i<6 ; i++) {
    passmatch[i]=6; // <<== Should be '6', not 6
}
```

is not assigning what you want it to assign. If you put quotes around this `6` as well, you would get the right content, but your program would remain broken, because `strcmp` requires null termination.

You can fix it in two ways:

- Add null termination to both C strings, either manually or by initializing with a string literal,
- Switch to using `memcmp`, which takes length, and therefore does not require null termination.